# Android Studio 1.5.1 Layout File Design View not updating

Tags: android, android-studio, preview

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 for the first time. Problem is that when I change the value of a TextView control either through its XML code or from its Properties window, it is not changed on Preview (Design View). However, when I test the application, it displays the updated value.
Here is screenshot...
[Value of TextView is changed in Properties window, but not updated on Layout Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il6GZ.png)

I have tried several things, like Clean, Rebuild, Invalidate Cache/Restart. My SDK and Android Studio is also updated...

**EDIT**
28-Feb-16

I have got a strange solution for this problem. Actually, I was trying to render my activity in Layout Design for API Level 23. I first opened activity_main.xml file and comment out the following xml code: -

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and also comment out this code: -

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

And then opened MainActivity.java file and comment out the following code: -

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

It solved my both problems. Now Design View of Layout file (content_main.xml) is updating as I change it in xml code. And also Design View is rendering successfully for API Level 23. Previously, it was creating Rendering Problems for API Level 23. As far as the rendering problems, I am understanding it somehow. But why Design View of Layout File is now updating?

Comment: no. app is running perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use preview for xml changes. android studio provides **preview** screen for view xml changes. it shows changes instantly so you can also view while doing changes and there is also refresh button there in case if you are not able to see changes by any technical error just press **refresh** button which will refresh the xml design.